# What is the function of __init__ method here

Tags: python

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,str1,str2):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.str1 = str1
        self.str2 = str2
    def run(self):
        run1(self.str1,self.str2)
```

I know the **__init__** is used to initialize a class but What is the its purpose in the next line.Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Second init method is used to call super class's init method to initialise.

Comment: see my answer @Talmoor

Comment: There's absolutely no need for you to create that `myThread` subclass, you can just use the `Thread` class itself, eg: `mythread = threading.Thread(target=run1, args=('a', 'b'))` `mythread.start()`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736131/python-threading-creation-of-a-subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` is used to initialize class objects. When you create a new object of `myThread`, it first calls `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` and then defines two attributes str1 and str2.

Note that you explicity call `threading.Thread`, which is the base class of `myThread`. It is better to refer the parent `__init__` method by `super(myThread, cls).__init__(self)`.

*Python docs*

> There are two typical use cases for **super**. In a class hierarchy with single inheritance, super can be used to refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly, thus making the code more **maintainable**. This use closely parallels the use of super in other programming languages.
>
> The second use case is to support cooperative **multiple inheritance in a dynamic execution environment**.

There are couple reasons derived classes calls base classes init.
One reason is if the base class does something special in it's `__init__` method. You may not even be aware of that.
The other reason is related to **OOP**. Let's say you have a base class and two subclasses that inherits from it.

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class SportCar(car):
    def __init__(self, color, maxspeed):
        super(SportCar, cls).__init__(self, color)
        self.maxspeed = maxspeed

 class MiniCar(car):
    def __init__(self, color, seats):
        super(MiniCar, cls).__init__(self, color)
        self.seats = seats
```

This is just to show an example, but you can see how both SportCar and MiniCar objects calls Car class using the `super(CURRENT_CLASS, cls).__init(self, PARAMS)` to run the initialize code in the base class. Note that you also need to maintain the code only in one place instead of repeating it in every class.

Comment: why is there a need to call **threading.Thread.__init__(self)**

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening here is that , you are inheriting from the class `threading.Thread` in your class `myThread`.

So all the functions that are in the `threading.Thread` class are available in your inherited class and you are modifying the function `__init__` in your class. So instead of running the init method of parent class , it will run  `__init__` method in your class.

So you need to make sure that the `__init__` method of parent class also runs before executing your modified `__init__` function. This is why the statement `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` is used . It just calls the `__init__` method of the parent class.